# Grid of images to fit window

Tags: html, css

I have 9 images with different sizes and different aspect ratios. I would like to create a 3 x 3 grid where each image will adjust its size to fill its cell and be centered in its cell. In addition, I want the grid to fill the browser window, and to rearrange itself if the browser window is resized.

The result should look something like this:[image: 3x3 grid image of "roll"]

I have tried using both `flex` and `grid` layouts, but I am sure that my attempts are much too complex and inelegant.

Thanks in advance for any advice on how to achieve this with simple CSS.

Comment: what have you tried so far? what would be your HTML? are you using any CSS framework?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `object-fit: cover;` and `object-position: center;` on **img** tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to dig into slightly more advanced CSS you might consider the [Pure CSS library](https://purecss.io). It's open source and similar to bootstrap but smaller and modular so it loads faster. They have a grid system that allows for such a thing. [This page](https://raintreepetscottsdale.com/services/) has a grid built with the Pure Grid module.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in different screen sizes:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE10 */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

/* Create four equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
  -ms-flex: 25%; /* IE10 */
  flex: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .column {
    -ms-flex: 50%;
    flex: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    -ms-flex: 100%;
    flex: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Photo Grid -->
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/falls2.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/paris.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/nature.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/mist.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/paris.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/ocean.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/mountainskies.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>  
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/falls2.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/paris.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/nature.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/mist.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/paris.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/ocean.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/mountainskies.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
```

I the example it shown as column wise, you can make your grids as row wise as well.

Answer (score 0):

Arange the images in a big  like below and give them the background image you want for each of them:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="img" style="bacground-image: url('image1-location')"></div>
  .
  .
  .
  <div class-"img" style="bacground-image: url('image9-location')"></div>
</div>
```

Then the css part should be something like this(note that the dimensions are just exemples)

```
.container {
  height:500px;
  width: 100%;
}

.img {
  width: 33%;
  height: auto;
  background-position: center;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

if you set the width to 33% then 3 containers should be on the same line.